# Rock Paper Scissors Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I have this code right now for my Rock Paper Scissors JS game.  In my compare function, I tried to program it so that it will display an alert message if either "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors" is not entered.  It does not work though, and I get no response when I enter in a different string than the 3 choices that work.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

var compchoice = function ()
{
    if (computerChoice <= 0.34)
    {
        return computerChoice = "Rock";
    } 
    else if(computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.35)
    {
        return computerChoice = "Paper";
    }
    if (computerChoice >= 0.68)
    {
        return computerChoice = "Scissors";
    }

};

var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (computerChoice === "Rock" || "Paper" || "Scissors")
    {
        if (choice1 === choice2)
        {
            return alert("The result is a tie!");
        }

        else if (choice1 === "Rock")
        {
            if (choice2 === "Scissors")
            {
                return alert("Rock crushes Scissors!");
            }
            else if (choice2 === "Paper")
            {
                return alert("Paper covers Rock!");
            }
        }
        if (choice1 === "Scissors")
        {
            if (choice2 === "Rock")
            {
                return alert("Rock crushes Scissors!");
            }
            else if (choice2 === "Paper")
            {
                return alert("Scissors cuts Paper!");
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "Paper")
        {
            if (choice2 === "Rock")
            {
                return alert("Paper covers Rock!");
            }
            else if (choice2 === "Scissors")
            {
                return alert("Scissors cuts Paper!");
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return alert("Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors next           time");
    }
};

compchoice();

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Any reasons why?

Comment: Lol... can you tell the answer was obvious... I'm watching more answers slide in... HEHE

Comment: now try Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock

Comment: You can clean up the code a bit if you use this:  `var computerChoice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));`   Then computerChoice is 0, 1 or 2 and you can use a switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`computerChoice === "Rock" || "Paper" || "Scissors"` is always true, since it parses as:

```
(computerChoice === "Rock") || ("Paper") || ("Scissors")
```

And `"Paper"` is a truthy value.

Also, you seem to be comparing `computerChoice`, not `userChoice`.

Fixed:

```
if (userChoice === "Rock" || userChoice === "Paper" || userChoice === "Scissors")
```

Or:

```
// array and indexOf
if (["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].indexOf(userChoice) > -1)
// doesn't work in IE8
```

Or:

```
// regex
if (/^(Rock|Paper|Scissors)$/.test(userChoice))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (computerChoice === "Rock" || computerChoice === "Paper" || computerChoice === "Scissors")
```

TADA!.... "Paper" as a string resolves as true :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in your first if in the compare:

```
if (computerChoice === "Rock" || "Paper" || "Scissors")
```

Should be:

```
if (computerChoice === "Rock" || computerChoice === "Paper" || computerChoice === "Scissors")
```

Edit: why you have this if statement in the first place does not make sense to me. You want to compare choice1 against choice2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do comparisons like this:

```
if (computerChoice === "Rock" || "Paper" || "Scissors")
```

You need to check each separately, like:

```
if(computerChoice === "Rock" || computerChoice === "Paper" || computerChoice === "Scissors")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given already, but you could optimize your code even more. This is what I would write:

```
var options=["Rock","Paper","Scissors"];
var beats=["crushes","covers","cuts"];
function play(choice){// "choice" = index of option

    if(choice<0||choice>options.length-1){alert("invalid input");}

    var loser=choice>0?choice-1:options.length-1; // what would lose from "choice"
    var winner=choice<options.length-1?choice+1:0; // what would beat "choice"
    switch(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)){ //chance of 1 in 3
        case 0: alert(options[choice]+beats[choice]+options[loser]); break;// win :-)
        case 1: alert(options[winner]+beats[winner]+options[choice]); break;// lose :-(
        case 2: alert("The result is a tie!"); break; 
    }
}
play(0);// 0=rock!
```

Since the chance is 1 in 3 you only have to create 3 static outcomes (win, lose or draw), and generate the message for it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the comparison to be userChoice like

```
if (userChoice === "Rock" || "Paper" || "Scissors")
    {
```